# Altering PDF through iTextSharp to Replace some existing text with a new text

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

Please tell me if is there any function in iTextSharp that dose replace(”xx”,”yy”) function in the pdf file without altering remaining parts of the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: **NO** you cannot do that with iText.

Longer Answer: PDF is a display format, so when the PDF is rendered many decisions are made about page and character layout and positioning.  Chapter 6 of [iText in Action](http://tinyurl.com/79bcxrg) has a great description in the introduction of why it is not a trivial task.  You can read [Chapter 6](http://www.manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter6.pdf) for free from the [publisher's website](http://www.manning.com/lowagie2/).

Comment: Thanks John, Can we use an existing PDF as background and then write the dynamic text on our desired place in the existing PDF. I am using C#. I am searching for a way to do this on the web but haven't found a workable yet.

Comment: I found a way to do this through PDF form Fields.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do this through PDF form Fields.

```
    String formFile = Server.MapPath("~/") + "source.pdf";

    String newFile = Server.MapPath("~/") + "sink.pdf";

    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(formFile);

    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create));

    AcroFields fields = stamper.AcroFields;

    // set form fields

    fields.SetField("{TO}", "John Doe");

    fields.SetField("{FROM}", "2 Milky Way, London");

    stamper.FormFlattening = true;

    stamper.Close();
```